# Custom order status is empty

Tags: magento2, orders, order-status, status

I create a new Order Status: Synced To B1
in `Sales > Orders` Status is empty for orders having this new status, but when I open order the status is here
Do you have any Idea How to show custom status in orders list grid?

Note That  I Updated the Status using REST API by POST to:
/rest/all/V1/orders/64/comments

```
{
  "statusHistory": {
    "comment": "Success Imported to SAP DocNum:89441",
    "created_at": "2019-06-03 08:20:27",
    "parent_id": 64,
    "is_customer_notified": 0,
    "is_visible_on_front": 1,
    "status": "SyncedtoB1"
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should come through

Clear cache

`php bin/magento cache:clean`

Run indexer

`php bin/magento index:reindex`

I'm wondering whether your order grid table is a bit behind

*Update based on comment*

First try this SQL query to sync status between order table and order grid table

```sql
update sales_order_grid sog, sales_order so set sog.status = so.status where sog.increment_id = so.increment_id
```

Next.  Are you setting custom status programatically?

If so code should look like this

```php
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;

public function __construct(
    OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    ...
) {
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
}

public function method($orderId) {
    $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
    $order->setStatus('whatever');

    try {
        $this->orderRepository->save($order);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // handle exception
    }
}
```

Comment: No, It's not fixed

Comment: I haven't access to mysql database, I Updated the Status using REST API by POST to /rest/all/V1/orders/64/comments => {"statusHistory": {"comment": "Success Imported to SAP DocNum:89441","created_at": "2019-06-03 08:20:27","parent_id": 64,"is_customer_notified": 0,"is_visible_on_front": 1,"status": "SyncedtoB1"}}

Comment: If you've got code access you've got sql access https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-write-custom-mysql-query/

Comment: No, I'm using C# to consume REST API, I haven't access to php code also

Comment: If you haven't got code or db access there is nothing I can suggest to fix